# Issue when connecting signal to slots in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5, signals-slots

I have developed an app in Qt/C++. I have added a thread to manage android device access and another thread for the UI management.

When running the app, I am sending different signals and receiving slots.

For some of them, I face an issue with the error below at runtime:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'uint32_t'
(Make sure 'uint32_t' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

What should I do? Is it necessary to make any changes in all classes or in main.cpp?

Comment: Have you tried registering `uint32_t`, using `qRegisterMetaType()`?

Comment: @Amartel. I don't really know where to do it.. is it a one shoot we can do in the main.cpp or I have to it in a class instantiation ?

Comment: You need to do it only once, before the first `connect`. Yes, you can do it in `main` function, or, even, statically like this: `static const int i00 = qRegisterMetaType < uint32_t >("uint32_t");`.

Comment: You may use `quint32`

Comment: For your reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to use `quint32` instead of `uint32_t` in the arguments of your signals and slots.  `quint32` is pre-registered in the meta-type system for you.